# pytest-asyncio RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running

Tags: pytest, playwright-python, pytest-asyncio

When trying to do UI automtion with pytest-asyncio and pytest-playwright, I got exception like: RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running

**Code structure:**

```
ui2/conftest.py
ui2/test_bing.py
```

**ui2/conftest.py**

```
import pytest
import asyncio


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def event_loop():
    """重写event_loop"""

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()
```

**ui2/test_bing.py**

```
import pytest

from playwright.async_api import Page


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_bing(page: Page):
    await page.goto("http://www.bing.com")
```

**env:**

```
pytest==7.1.2
pytest-asyncio==0.18.3
pytest-playwright==0.3.0
```

**Detail exception as below:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because you're importing from the `async_api` it sounds like you're writing asynchronous integration tests that you want to run **concurrently**. `pytest-asyncio` runs coroutine tests serially, so you instead want to use `pytest-asyncio-cooperative`. (If you wanted the tests run serially you should use `from playwright.sync_api import Page`.) I'd suggest:

1. Install pytest-asyncio-cooperative

```
pip install pytest-asyncio-cooperative
```

2. Remove `event_loop` fixture from `ui2/conftest.py`. `pytest-asyncio-cooperative` runs all test coroutines asynchronously on the same event loop implicitly.
3. Mark your async tests with `@pytest.mark.asyncio_cooperative`

```py
import pytest

from playwright.async_api import Page


@pytest.mark.asyncio_cooperative
async def test_bing(page: Page):
    await page.goto("http://www.bing.com")
```

4. Run your tests with the `-p no:asyncio` option. `pytest-aysncio` is not compatible with `pytest-asyncio-cooperative`, so it has to be disabled or uninstalled.

```
pytest -p no:asyncio
```

Answer (score -1):

Short solution.

Install nest_asyncio:

```
pip install nest_asyncio
```

Then add this to your main conftest.py file:

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

Find a more detailed explanation over here:

https://pypi.org/project/nest-asyncio/